# How to recover suppressed files from a project?

Tags: jdeveloper

I was working on my project on JDeveloper since several days, and today I wanted to create a new project related to this one so I imported all the files, but finally i decided to remove them so i selected them and clicked suppress.

I thought that would just remove them from the new project but it did erase all my classes.

Do you have any way in order to retrieve those files?

It can be related to Windows or to Oracle I don't have any clue to wich thing i have to do in order to recover those lost files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for those who could expect the same issue : 
Right click on application source then Restore from local History. 
It saved my day, i hope it'll save yours !